# What is the English term to say job quitting?

Tags: word-choice

Say, we often use the term "lay-off" to express the meaning that the company is laying off their employees because it is not making any profit at this moment.

Now, there is other situation when the company is doing OK but most of the employees don't like to work for the company because the jobs are too boring. So, many employees are quitting their jobs daily.

Is it OK to say this sentence and is there a better way to express it?

> The job quitting rate in this company is very high.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

"Staff turnover," is what I believe you are after.

As in:

> "The staff turnover was very high due to low morale."

As it says on [this 2014 fact sheet](http://www.cipd.co.uk/hr-resources/factsheets/employee-turnover-retention.aspx):

> **Employee turnover**
>
> Employee turnover refers to the proportion of employees ***who leave an organisation*** over a set period (often on a year-on-year basis), expressed as a percentage of total workforce numbers.
>
> At its broadest, the term is used to encompass all leavers, both voluntary and involuntary, including those who resign, retire or are made redundant, in which case it may be described as ‘overall’ or ‘crude’ employee turnover. **It is also possible to calculate more specific breakdowns of turnover data, such as redundancy-related turnover or resignation levels, with the latter particularly useful** for employers in assessing the effectiveness of people management in their organisations
>
> <sup>(emphasis added)</sup>

Comment: Good one, but that does not say if employees  resigned or were fired.

Comment: @Josh61 - You didn't, by chance, click on the link, did you?

Comment: @J.R. - Yes,I did:  ***Turnover*** : (Human resource management)  The number of employees hired to replace ***those who left or were fired*** during a 12 month period. http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/turnover.html

Comment: @Josh61 - in popular use however 'turnover' usually refers to those who have left of their own volition.

Comment: @Jascol - I agree, but the definition is wider than *resignation rate*, which I think OP was looking for. Anyway it is ok now that you have posted the full definition.

Comment: @Josh - I was talking about the link that was posted in this answer.

Answer (score 17):

*Attrition rate* is a commonly used term to describe the proportion of employees voluntarily leaving the company, through resignation or retirement.

*Edit*: I do not really follow why some people want a "definition" for a term so commonly used in the industry. Nonetheless, here are your links.

> A factor, normally expressed as a percentage, reflecting the degree of losses of personnel or materiel due to various causes within a specified period of time.

– [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/attrition+rate)

> Formula:
>
> Attrition rate (%) = (Number of employees resigned during the month / Average number of employees during the month) x 100 
> where Average number of employees during the month = (Total number of employees at the start of the month + Total number of employees at the end of the month) / 2.

– [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Churn_rate#Employee_moves.2Fattrition_rate)

See also this article:
[Infosys's attrition rate crosses 20%](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/tech/jobs/Infosyss-attrition-rate-crosses-20/articleshow/44770843.cms)

There are plenty of articles like this one.

Answer (score 12):

[Resignation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/resignation) :

> - An oral or written statement that one is resigning a position or office:
>
>   - He submitted his resignation

(The Free Dictionary )

A more common and formal way to express your concept is:

- The ***resignation rate***  in this company is very high,

Answer (score 5):

An informal term is "churn" or "churn rate". This can describe either the rate at which customers change between competing suppliers (for internet services, satellite TV networks, etc), or to workers in jobs like fast food sales or call centers, which are regarded as short-term jobs rather than long-term careers.
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/churn-rate

Comment: I think this is the closest to the accepted answer, and a good substitute/addition

Comment: "Turnover Rate" would mean the same thing, and is much more common at least where I live.

Answer (score 3):

To [**resign**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/resign#Verb) means

> To quit (a job or position).

---

You can find example [here](http://www.acas.org.uk/index.aspx?articleid=3968)

> Employees may terminate their contract by **resigning** or an employer may terminate the contract by dismissing an employee.

Answer (score 2):

If the company is doing poorly, and a lot of employees are leaving the company for greener pastures, I would call it an **exodus of employees**, especially if it leaves the company thinly staffed.  (Contrast that with *turnover*, which implies that the company is able to replace the workers who left.)

Comment: Good answer with respect to the particular use the OP was looking for. Personally I'd put the word *mass* in front to make it a **mass exodus**.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest the best word for doing this act is **[Retire](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=retire&use1828=on)** or [Retiring](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=retiring&use1828=on). Retire is defined as:

> 1. To withdraw; to retreat; *to go from company* or from a public place into privacy; as, to retire from the world; to retire from notice. [emphasis my own]

Example: "[Record Number of Teachers Set to Retire](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=18583812)"(1)

The word you're looking for is **[Retirement](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=retirement&use1828=on)**:

> 1. The act of withdrawing from company or from public notice or station.

In the modern day, we speak of things such as [Retirement Plans](http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Plan-Sponsor/Types-of-Retirement-Plans-1)(2) or [Retirement Rates](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://scholar.harvard.edu/stock/files/why_are_retirement_rates_so_high_at_age_65.pdf&sa=U&ved=0CCUQFjABahUKEwi3hZCw9pPGAhWTNYgKHVXKBIo&sig2=YXqFUgovYPwriAoFy8eRBQ&usg=AFQjCNF4Eju4cilxzPt9nxqZ54Oov46CKg)(3)

We refer to a person so withdrawn as simply [Retired.](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=retired&use1828=on) This may sometimes be made into a proper title, [The Retired](https://www.icas.com/icas-membership/membership-for-the-retired) (4), to refer to significant socioeconomic groups of such people, sometimes requiring further specification of which group is retired. Other connotations for the word exist, such as voluntary withdrawal from society or the dissolution of business but the connotation of quitting one's job or position is the primary use.

1. N.P.R. (National Public Radio)
2. Types of Retirement Plans, I.R.S. (Internal Revenue Service)
3. Why  Are Retirement Rates  So High  at Age  65? Robin  L. Lumsdaine, James  H.  Stock, and David A. Wise (scholar.harvard.edu)
4. I.C.A.S (Institution of Chartered Accountants of Scotland) Membership for The Retired

All referenced dictionary definitions come from [Noah Webster's American Dictionary of the English Language](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/), (1828).

Comment: This term only works, though, when the workers quit without any intention of finding another job, or continuing their career at another firm.